# What is the best way to binary search an array via another array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, binary-search

What would be the best way to do a binary search in an array that you can actually access it *via indirection*?
Meaning I have an `Integer[]` that stores the indexes of a `String[]` that represent the sorted version of the `String[]`
E.g. `Integer[] idxes= {5, 4, 0, 3 , 1, 2}` which means that the `String[5]` or `String[idxes[0]]` is the lowest string lexicographically.
I hope the description is clear.
What would be the best way to do a binary search via the `idexes` for a `String` if it is part of the `String[] words` ?

What I did is the following:

```
int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(idexes, -1, new Comparator<Integer>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {

    if(o1 == -1){
        return k.compareTo(words[o2]);
    }
    else{
        return words[o1].compareTo(k);
      }         
    }
});
```

where `k` is the search word and `words[]` is the `String[]` I mentioned earlier.
This works, but I don't like the `-1` I pass in the `binarySearch` api.
Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Not technically an answer but encapsulating the String array and the index array into its own class can at least help hide this implementation detail from the rest of the application. I also don't think it's THAT bad, it doesn't look nice but it's relatively simple, especially with some added comments explaining the rationale.

Comment: Having said that, if you search the same array often, you're better off creating a sorted copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class SortedListView extends AbstractList<String> implements RandomAccess {
  // stringArray, idxes should be fields, initialized in a constructor
  public int size() {
    return stringArray.length;
  }
  public String get(int index) {
    return stringArray[idxes[index]];
  }
};
```

Then you can use `Collections.binarySearch` on that `List`.

Comment: +1!One question.Why `extends AbstractList` and not `implements List<String>`?

Comment: If you just `implement List<String>`, then you need to implement every single `List` method individually -- there are at least a dozen different methods.  `AbstractList` fills in that skeleton for you.  Initially I thought an anonymous class would suffice, but for `Collections.binarySearch` you really need to implement `RandomAccess` for best results, so you need an actual named class.